Is it possible to access digital identification data from a Dell charger on ChromeOS?
I'm looking for ways to retrieve metadata or unique identification details from a Dell charger/adapter when connected to a ChromeOS device. From what I understand, Dell chargers include a digital chip for authentication and communication, possibly transmitting information like wattage or identifiers.
Specifically, I’d like to know:

Does ChromeOS provide tools or APIs to access such metadata via Apps or Extensions?
Are there any system logs or utilities in ChromeOS that can display this kind of information?
What limitations, if any, exist on retrieving data from connected chargers on ChromeOS?

I’m interested in safely accessing this information without modifying hardware or reverse engineering. Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Superuser. On this site we require that each post have a single question. You have asked at least three. Also, questions asking that we recommend software or hardware products are generally off topic. Questions that tend to get better and more helpful attention will also demonstrate the research and effort the asker has put in to solving the problem themselves prior to asking here. Your question doesn't have any of that. Finally, you're asked if its POSSIBLE, which is different than asking HOW to do something. Please EDIT your question to fix these issues.
